# How can I read "Terminal Services Private Data" from the clipboard?

Tags: windows-runtime, clipboard, terminal-services

When I look at the clipboard all I am getting is a IRandomAccessStream under the name "Terminal Services Private Data". This is what happens when you copy files from the desktop but you're running your app in the simulator. I would like to try to read this data, does anyone know where I can find documentation to find out what's in the stream? It is the same format and value type if you copy multiple files or one.

Comment: I think it's clear from the name of the format that it is undocumented.

Answer (score 0):

You could write a little app to dump that out as a string, or hex values.  I bet if you got a good look at it, the format would be apparent.